# How to DIFF datetime?

Tags: mysql

This should return 1.

```
SELECT DATETIMEDIFF('2011-02-15 12:00:00', '2011-02-14 12:00:00');
```

This should return 0.

```
SELECT DATETIMEDIFF('2011-02-15 12:00:00', '2011-02-14 13:00:00');
```

TIMEDIFF calculation doesn't include day, month, year; DATEDIFF calculation doesn't include hour, minute, second. How to do diff datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

will this do ?

```
select date1 - date2
from table
```

if both columns date1 and date2 are `Date` type

Or to get seconds

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date1, date2)    
FROM table
```

Comment: Yes! TIMESTAMPDIFF is exactly what I want! "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2011-02-14 12:00:00', '2011-02-15 11:00:00');" returns 0. Thank you.